# safari extension: Sending message from injected script to popover

Tags: popover, addeventlistener, message, safari-extension

im busy with creating a bookmaker extension in safari and running up against the following issue. In my popover i've a iframe which includes a button. When that button (submit button) is clicked the following message must be send:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e){
    if(e.data.command == 'closeSymbalooBookmarker'){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            window.close();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

as you can see this close the popover in 2 seconds (the above script is made in chrome extension).

I need to send a message from the inject script to a popover so i can close the popover in the popover window. Or is there some other way to that?

Thank u.

Comment: no one here who ca help me out with this one?

Answer (score 1):

The global page is the best place to receive messages from an injected script.

Do something like this:

#### global.js

```
safari.application.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);
function handleMessage(msg) {
    if (msg.name === 'hidepopover') {
        safari.extension.popovers[0].hide()
    }
}
```

#### injected.js

```
setTimeout(function() {
    safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('hidepopover');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: made a mistake, it didn't work afterall :( the popups hide when you click on it immediately. It has to be hidden afer the user clicked on the submit button in the iframe that contains in the popover.html